# PIP error on MacOS

Tags: macos, python, pip

I'm trying to use PIP in my Mac but it doesn't work. What is missing and how can I fix it?

```
pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==18.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a thin wrapper of pip and virtualenv. It allow you create independent pip environments, that do not interfere with each other and the global pip config. Perhaps it will help bypass your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is there the problem in the path of Python, is it possible you have removed.

In this case use these commands:

```
brew --prefix /lib/python2.7/site-packages

pip install -U pip 

pip3 install --upgrade pip

brew install pipenv
```